Optimized Method to Calc Real Rates of Return From Monthly Nominal Rates
I wrote the following VBA code to calculate real rates of return using Robert Shiller's dataset:
Note: This calculation is for forecasted returns so I have no prices available to do the calculation by creating an index from the prices. The forecasted nominal returns are the sum of three components: the initial dividend yield, the forecasted earnings rate of growth, and the forecasted p/e effect over the time period.
Public Function CalcMonthlyRealForecastReturnAmt(ShillerID As Long, NominalReturn As Double, Period As Long) As Double
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim MonthlyReturn As Double
Dim MonthlyRealReturn As Double
Dim InflationRate As Double
Dim FirstRealReturn As Double
Dim CumulativeRealReturn As Double
Dim EndShillerID As Long

EndShillerID = ShillerID + (Period * 12)

MonthlyReturn = (NominalReturn + 1) ^ (1 / 12) - 1

InflationRate = DLookup("MonthlyInflationRate", "ShillerSpData", "ShillerID = " & ShillerID)
FirstRealReturn = ((1 + MonthlyReturn) / (1 + InflationRate)) - 1

CumulativeRealReturn = FirstRealReturn + 1

ShillerID = ShillerID + 1

Do While ShillerID <= EndShillerID
  InflationRate = DLookup("MonthlyInflationRate", "ShillerSpData", "ShillerID = " & ShillerID)
  MonthlyRealReturn = ((1 + MonthlyReturn) / (1 + InflationRate)) - 1
  CumulativeRealReturn = CumulativeRealReturn * (MonthlyRealReturn + 1)
  ShillerID = ShillerID + 1
Loop

Debug.Print "EndShillerID: " & EndShillerID

Debug.Print "Total Nominal Return: " & (1 + MonthlyReturn) ^ 12 - 1
Debug.Print "Total Real Return: " & CumulativeRealReturn ^ (1 / Period) - 1

CalcMonthlyRealForecastReturnAmt = CumulativeRealReturn ^ (1 / Period) - 1

Exit_Handler:
  Exit Function

Err_Handler:
  clsErrorHandler.HandleError "modORForecastReport", "CalcMonthlyRealForecastReturnAmt"
  Resume Exit_Handler

End Function

It's slow. Are there any alternative methods to find the real rate that would be faster?
Thanks in Advance.
